# Return to app from ACTION_BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS after user connects to device

Tags: android, bluetooth

In my app i display bluetooth settings to user, so he can turn on bluetooth and connect to device.

```
Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(settingsIntent);
```

Then it should return to my app. Is there a way to return to my app when some device is connected?

I know about Intent-Fillters

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED" />
</intent-filter>
```

But if i understand them properly, they will run my app everytime some bluetooth device is connected, and all i want is just way to return focus from bluetooth settings to my app.

Answer (score 0):

I think the standard way to do this is to use the built in enable bluetooth activity.

```
if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
    Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
    startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
}
```

Connect to the device from your code.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#SettingUp

Comment: I don't want to code connecting or enabling bluetooth in my app. I want to use provided ACTION_BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS, which enables both, and more. All i want is way to close this view after user connects to device.